# How to place the destination folders in a list - each on a separate line - using Windows command script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, copy-paste

Please bear with me, I'm not an expert on this.

I currently have this working:

```
Start C:\FastCopy\FastCopy.exe ^
     /exclude="X:\Apps\first directory\";^
     X:\System\Temp\;^
     X:\System\INetCache\ ^

"X:\Apps" "X:\Backup" "X:\Download" "X:\_D_2.txt" ^
     /to="Y:\os2 - %datestamp% %timestamp%\"
```

How can I place the destination folders in a list - each on a separate line, like this:

```
Start C:\FastCopy\FastCopy.exe ^
    /exclude="X:\Apps\first directory\";^
              X:\System\Temp\;^
              X:\System\TMP\;^
              X:\System\INetCache\ ^
   "X:\Apps"
   "X:\Backup"
   "X:\Download"
   "X:\_D_2.txt" ^
   /to="Y:\folder - %datestamp% %timestamp%\"
```

Comment: The caret is the line continuation character, you should add it to all lines, but the last

Comment: Why do you have double quotes on the first and last three paths but not two to four. Also, you actually have whitespace in there as is. I am not sure about the DOS part either, though you have OS2 in one of the paths 